# How can a dropdown be used to filter Splunk query results

Tags: token, dropdown, splunk

I am trying to add a dropdown to my dashboard that will allow the user to choose which field to count.

The following is my query:

```
index='splunk_demo' source='demo.zip'
| fields Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price|table Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price
| chart count(Name) by Model.New
```

I want to add the `Model.New` and `Model.Old` to the dropdown and when the user picks one of them in the dropdown it will count the Name field by either `Model.New` or `Model.Old`.

I would like the query for `chart count` at the end of my existing query to be either query 1 or query 2 based on the user's choice as follows:

Query 1:

```
index='splunk_demo' source='demo.zip'
| fields Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price
|table Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price
| chart count(Name) by Model.New
```

Query 2:

```
index='splunk_demo' source='demo.zip'
| fields Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price
|table Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price
| chart count(Name) by Model.Old
```

I'm not sure what I should use for the token and once I have the token how and where I need to use it in order for my `count` command to work.

I tried adding the dropdown and clicked on the Edit option to go in and add the label but I don't know how to add the token to my query and where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this will be to create a list in your dropdown who entry *values* are the field names (ie `Model.Old` & `Model.New`)

Call the name of that token, say, `modelchoice`

Then have a single search on your dashboard that looks like this:

```
index='splunk_demo' source='demo.zip'
| fields Name, Model.New, Model.Old, Price
| chart count(Name) by $modelchoice$
```

Splunk does a straight substitution when it encounters a token with whatever the token's value is.

So if the token's value is the field name, it will substitute that in